# Call 'script' command and exit it from within a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, command

I'm using the linux 'script' command http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/script1.html to log all input and output in an interactive bash script.

At the moment I have to call the `script` command, then run my bash script, then `exit`.

I want to run the `script` and `exit` commands from within the actual bash script itself.  How can I do this?

I've tried `script -a` but that doesn't work for interactive scripts.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"script" forks a shell (or a command specified with "-c"), so I don't think you can call "script" from within the script you want to "script".

Take this (annoyingly) interactive shell script (called "fred"):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -p 'Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left? ' WHO
do
        :
done
```

Run it and "script" the interaction to a file:

```
[myles@marklar ~]$ script -c ~/fred fred.log
Script started, file is fred.log
Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left? Repeat
Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left? Repeat
Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left? Repeat
Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left? Script done, file is fred.log
```

The log file contains:

```
[myles@marklar ~]$ cat fred.log
Script started on Mon 12 Nov 2012 11:44:41 PM EST
Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left? Repeat
Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left? Repeat
Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left? Repeat
Pete and Repeat were on a boat. Pete jumped off. Who was left?
Script done on Mon 12 Nov 2012 11:44:51 PM EST
```

In short, you'll have to call your interactive shell script with the "script" command, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially redirect all output of your script to a file using the following construct:

```
exec &> /your/script.log
```

In addition, bash allows you to log all commands it executes, all input it receives, and all expansions it performs when you add the following:

```
set -x
```

If these are the first two lines of your script, everything that the script is doing will be logged.